# WordPress jQuery working but not the alert function

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress plugin and I've included jQuery. For some very strange reason the `alert` function is not being shown. See code below:

```
$("#my_button").click(function() {
      alert('before hide/show');  
      $('#divA').hide();
      $('#divB').show();
      alert('after hide/show'); 
});
```

In the code above `divA` is actually hidden and `divB` is shown, so it means jQuery *is* working, *but* strangely enough none of the `alert` are being shown.

I am running the code from the plugin options page in the backend.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you getting any error, Check your browser console.

Comment: Are you sure it's this code block that's actually running?

Comment: First check if this block is actually being executed by adding some css to the divs. like border or background-color. And then check if the Alert function is not overridden anywhere in the code.

Comment: @ Satch3000: Your browser has a fully-featured debugger built into it. Set a breakpoint on the first alert and click the button. I suspect Rory's right, and the code you think is running isn't in fact the code running. Perhaps the browser has a cached copy of your code, for instance, that isn't getting refreshed.

Comment: Can't believe it...It was the browser cache (firefox) :o/

Answer (score 1):

The problem was Firefox Cache. It was the last thing I expected it to be but after doing an Alt F5 it started working.

Not sure, if it's Wordpress issue or just the FF browser but this sorted it for me.

Can't believe it was the most simple thing :o/ Lesson learned... If the code doesn't work and it's not making sense, press ALT F5 First.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is working fine.
you can see in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3R3Ss/).

check your other code. May your another function or something else is preventing to show alert?

Or put your code in ONLOAD on form.

```
$(function() {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you called any jQuery file

Try by adding following before your code

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **alert** function is override by some other code. That 's the reason why it doesn't show the alert box.

You can look at this example then you can understand what I mean

```
function alert(param)
{
// do nothing
}

alert("Call message"); // this will not show up anything because the system function is override
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. It was not doing a simple alert. The way I solved was just including jQuery.(document).ready **after** `wp_enqueue_script` like this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'load_jquery' );
function load_jquery() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
?>

//call jQuery
jQuery.(document).ready(function(){
  alert('test');
});
```